# RandomForestRegressor: questions about output, parameters and execution time

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, optional-parameters, execution-time

I have used the following code to run and evaluate a `RandomForestRegressor` model for my data:

My dataset is 36 features, 1 label with around 31 million rows. The features are continuous and the labels are binary.

I have the following questions:

1. When I use `np.unique(Y_Pred)` it tells me `array([0. , 0.5, 1. ])`. Why am I getting 0.5 as an output? Is there a parameter I can change in the model to fix it? I don't know whether to include it as a 1 or 0. For now I've included it as a 1 (hence Y_Pred > 0.45 in my code).
2. The documentation says the most important parameters to adjust are `n_estimators` and `max_features`. For `n_estimators` what is a reasonable number? I've started at 2 because of how slow it took to run on my TPU Google Colab session (43 minutes for each tree or 86 minutes total). Should I bother increasing trees to improve accuracy? Are there any other parameters I can change to improve speed? All of my features are reasonably important so I don't want to start dropping them.
3. Is there anything I am doing wrong that is making it slow, or anything I can do to make it faster?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. When your labels are `binary`, you should use the `RandomForestClassifier` so that you can get the `1` or `0` as the output directly from the model.
2. you could play around with the `max_samples` parameter to reduce the number of datapoints used for each tree in the random forest. Since you have 31 millions records, it make sense to subsample them for each tree.
3. `max_depth` has greatly help you to reduce the training time. You need to find the sweet spot the get a balance between computation time and model performance.